# NSPredicate iPhone 3.2 SDK Core Data "IN clause" NSInvalidArgumentException exception

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I have a collection of `Calendar` objects and want to query them by their `service_id` property. I'm using Core Data on iPhone 3.2 SDK with sqlite.

`calendars` is a NSArray result of a `NSFetchRequest`. I'm plucking the `service_id` property out of each object in the `NSArray.`

```
NSPredicate *tripsWithServiceId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"service_id IN %@", [calendars valueForKey:@"service_id"]];
```

However this generates an exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (service_id IN {"DEC10-Multi-Weekday-01", "MAR11-Multi-Weekday-01", "MAR11-Multi-Weekday-02"})'
```

The following SQL query in the sqlite console will return the results I expect:

```
select ztrip.zservice_id from ztrip WHERE ztrip.zservice_id IN ("DEC10-Multi-Sunday-01", "DEC10-Multi-Sunday-01");
```

I'm just trying to replicate that with NSPredicate if that helps.

Tried re-reading the docs, and tried out a number of proposed fixes. Checked in IRC and someone else thought the syntax looked fine. Any tips? Totally stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed. Seems like the NSPredicate supports an array with the "IN" clause just fine. The real problem was in my application, I had typo'd the column name in the data model tool in Xcode ("service_Id" instead of "service_id") which I suspect caused SQL generation problems because it couldn't find the correct column name. I fixed the model .h and .m files and the "IN" clause works as expected now.

Comment: Yup, that solved it for me. Programmer error, and it basically means you typed in the wrong attribute key to match.

Comment: Write down your comment as an answer, and accept it! I'll upvote it