# How to use the "ALL" aggregate operation in a NSPredicate to filter a CoreData-based collection

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

Based on the data model below

[image: dataModel]

And based on user input I create a NSSet of managedObjects of entity Tag called *selectedTags*.

---

### My problem:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY entryTags IN %@", selectedTags];
```

... this will return *any* Entry with at least one entryTag that is in the selectedTags set.

I want something along the lines of:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL entryTags IN %@", selectedTags];
```

... notice the only change is the "ANY" to "ALL". This illustrates what I want, but does not work.

To formulate the outcome I expect:

I'm looking for a solution that will return only Entries who's entryTags are all in the selectedTags list (but at the same time, if possible, not necessarily the other way around).

To further illustrate:

(tag)Mom
(tag)Dad
(tag)Gifts

(entry)she is a she.....(tag)mom
(entry)he is a he........(tag)dad
(entry)gifts for mom...(tags:)mom, gifts
(entry)gifts for dad.....(tags:)dad, gifts

If selectedTags contains "mom" and "gifts", then the entry "gifts for dad" will show up, since it has the tag "gifts". I'd rather have it not show :)

Comment: Clarification: is `selectedTags` another entity or is it an attribute or relationship of `Entries`? Is `entryTags` an attribute or a relationship?

Comment: I've been looking at your answers and hoping that you would chime in on this :D I updated the question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the definite answer so far:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(entryTags, $tag, $tag IN %@).@count = %d", selectedTags, [selectedTags count]];
```

B-E-A-U-T-I-F-U-L.

Thanks to Dave DeLong.

Comment: I wasn't sure if selectedTags had to be an NSArray or NSSet so I tested it both ways and either one works.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks! (And now I know about subqueries too)

Answer (score 5):

How about using a compound predicate? As I understand you want to return all Entries that match a list of tags not just any of them. One approach would be to create a predicate for each tag, then AND them together using a compound predicate.

```
NSMutableArray *predicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (Tag *tag in selectedTags) {
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY entryTags.tagName MATCHES %@", tag.tagName]];
}
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```

This should achieve want you want. Then just set this predicate on your request.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this code. Care to elaborate? I want to return all Entry objects where Entry.entryTags contain all of the Tag objects in selectedTags.

Comment: basically you want to return all Entries that match a list of tags that you have. So you write a predicate for each tag you want to match against. So your predicate would be something like return any entry which has a tag that matches this tag name. Then you AND all those predicates for each tag together and you get the intersection of all the results which is the Entries that have all the tags in selectedTags. I've edited my answer above to use your variable names.

Comment: Very clean solution. Much more readable to the average obj c developer than the SUBQUERY predicate.

Comment: This answer worked well for me, and as far as I can tell my needs matched those explained in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do what you want with a predicate.

The `ANY` and `ALL` operators apply to the entity being tested (in this case `Entry`) and not the contents of the collection (`selectedTags`). Either operator will return an `Entry` object that matches any single element of the collection. The `ANY` operator will return the first match it finds while the `ALL` operator will return all matches. In neither case will they return an entry that matches every element in the provided collection.

(It also looks like you are trying to use actual `Tag` objects in `selectedTags`. That will most likely not work either because object compares on classes without dedicated comparison methods usually fail. It is also slow. You need to compare attributes in predicates.)

Since you already have the `Tag` objects you want, to find the candidate related `Entity` objects, you just have to walk the `Tag.taggedEntries` relationship. Then you have to find the intersection of all the sets of `Entity` object to find only those `Entity` objects that are related to ***every*** selected `Tag` bject. Since there isn't an intersect collections operator, you need a loop.

```
if ([selectedEntries count]>=2) {
    NSMutableSet *intersectEntries=[[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    for (int i=1; i<[selectedTags count]; i++) {
        if ([intersectEntries count]==0) {            
            [intersectEntries unionSet:[[selectedEntries objectAtIndex:(i-1)] valueForKey:@"taggedEntries"]];
        }        
        [intersectEntries intersectSet:[[selectedEntries objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"taggedEntries"]];
    }
}
```

(Note: I didn't test this but it should work.)

Now `intersectEntries` should contain only those `Entry` objects that are related to every selected tag.

Answer (score 2):

I realized I could give something back here for the guidance that I have previously gotten. By using the code TechZen supplied I was able to come up with the following -- and for me highly valued -- piece of code:

```
- (NSArray *)unionSetOfObjectsForObjects:(NSArray *)objects {

    NSMutableSet *unionSetOfObjects = [NSMutableSet set];

    if (objects.count)
        [unionSetOfObjects unionSet:[[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"key"]];
       //unionSetOfObjects = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"key"];

    if (objects.count > 1)
        for (id object in objects)
            [unionSetOfObjects intersectSet:[object valueForKey:@"key"]];

    return unionSetOfObjects.allObjects;
}
```

If it is not immediately obvious what this code does:

It collects all the values (in my case objects) for the key `key` on all of the objects provided in the `objects` array.

This code just... tastes good, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entryTags IN %@", selectedTags];
```

You don't need the ALL clause. It's also documented here:

[Predicate Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)

And as you can see in this post the user does it successfully (read the comments to the original question)

[NSPredicate iPhone 3.2 SDK Core Data “IN clause”...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062881/nspredicate-iphone-3-2-sdk-core-data-in-clause-nsinvalidargumentexception-exce)