# NSPredicate Compare Two Sets And Many-To-Many Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Two model classes

```
AUser
- name

AGroup
- users
```

Groups and Users share a many-to-many relationship.

I wish to check whether two sets share the exact same users (not more users or less users)

But unfortunately I am getting the following error: *to-many key not allowed here*

Note that I have looked at other SO questions but none seemed to fit because I have tried to use their methodologies for the past 2 hours, but I could not get it to work. Or at least I did not understand them very well.

Also is my predicate alright for comparing two mutable sets?

```
- (BOOL)conversationExists:(NSMutableSet *)members {
    NSFetchRequest *request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AGroup" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"users==%@",members]; 
    //There is more code that I have not shown here as it is irrelevant to the question
    //Mainly The NSPredicate line is the problem
}
```

Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it.

From,
*New iOS programmer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does it need to be a predicate?

What's wrong with `[[groups valueForKey:@"users"] isEqualToSet:members]`?

Comment: I just thought you needed to use predicates for Fetch Requests using Core Data (or at least all the examples I saw only used predicates). Thanks, by the way!

Comment: You do if you use a `NSFetchRequest`, but you don't need to use a `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: This may sound like a silly question. I am just curious, before I checkmark this question, does this check all groups?

Comment: If it works at all, it should, but I now have my doubts: `[groups valueForKey:@"users"]` *ought to* return a set of sets. You might need a ["collection operator"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-SW7), perhaps `[groups valueForKey:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.users"]`

Comment: At the moment this solution, while it does seem like a much better and quicker approach then using an NSFetchRequest, is not working. I am going to try and work out what's the issue. Thanks once again @tc.

Comment: Nope, despite `members` and `each group` having the same users, it just says False.

Comment: @GangstaGraham: Your question title suggest that you have two *AGroup* objects and want to compare their users. In this case something like in this answer should work. - Or do you want to find **all** *AGroup* objects that have a given set of users. In that case a fetch request is the correct solution, see Patrick Tescher's answer or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13086353/1187415.

Comment: I just realized members and users are NSMutableSets rather than NSSets I think this might be part of the problem. Can you check the equality of two NSMutableSets? @Martin R  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287706/equality-of-two-nsmutablesets

Comment: @GangstaGraham: `isEqualToSet` works with mutable sets without problems. Perhaps you can clarify what you are trying to achieve (compare two group objects or fetch a list of group objects, see my above comment).

Comment: Thanks to Martin , this was solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287706/equality-of-two-nsmutablesets-using-custom-class-attributes/ 

Yes, from the information you had @tc. you were correct. Therefore, you get an upvote, checkmark, and a chocolate chip cookie! Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 2):

This post had an answer: [How to use the "ALL" aggregate operation in a NSPredicate to filter a CoreData-based collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302611/how-to-use-the-all-aggregate-operation-in-a-nspredicate-to-filter-a-coredata-b)

Essentially something like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(members, $member, $member IN %@).@count = %d", members, [members count]];
```

Comment: Pardon my lack of SQL knowledge but what do `$member` and `$member IN` refer to. Also, I got the following error: `Can't have a non-relationship collection element in a subquery` I think I might be able to solve this issue once I understand the SQL a little better. Also instead of SUBQUERY(members, etc.) shouldn't it be SUBQUERY(users, etc.) unless I am mistaken. Sorry about my lack of knowledge lol. Thanks though!

Comment: Yes, I did not get the error when I used `users` instead of `members`, so thanks! and I assume $member is just a temporary variable? Am I correct @PatrickTescher

Comment: Ah yes, users not members. the $member is just temporary.

Comment: Hmm..this seems to work sometimes and other times, this causes an error: Cocoa error 1580  NSValidationErrorValue = "Relationship 'users' on managed object  I will investigate this issue and once I get it working I will upvote and checkmark!

Comment: Note that this predicate also yields true if the members of the object are *a superset* of the given memberlist. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084930/how-to-create-a-core-data-predicate-to-test-that-a-relation-contains-all-given-o/13086353#13086353 for an example how to check for exact equality.

Comment: @PatrickTescher   This was a good answer given the information you had and what I had asked for, so I upvoted it. For the final answer that I went with, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287706/equality-of-two-nsmutablesets-using-custom-class-attributes/