# Equality of Two NSMutableSets Using Custom Class Attributes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, equality, nsmutableset

How do you **check if two `NSMutableSets` are equal** (*same members, same number of members*)?

My implementation of `isEqualToSet` does not seem to be working.

```
// members is a NSMutableSet of AUser objects

// users is also a NSMutableSet of AUser objects, it is an attribute of instances of the AGroup class

[[group valueForKey:@"users"] isEqualToSet:members]


AGroup
- users

AUser
- name  (String)
```

How do I check if the sets are equal by checking their name attributes?

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, it's my first time with iOS programming, so I only know the basics at the moment.

Comment: `isEqualToSet:` should work. maybe it is the problem of the objects in the set. they should implement `isEqual:` and `hash`

Comment: What is the contents of your set?  strings or numbers or other others?  "`isEqualToSet`" might only looking at the addresses of the objects in the set to determine equality. But looking at the above comment, maybe it's looking at the contents of certain types of objects, too.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks you helped me understand the problem. I will post an update to the question with what's wrong. The objects in the set are two instances of custom classes, which do have a String attribute although I do not know how to check attributes.

Comment: Updated. Do I still need to implement isEqual in these custom classes, which I have not done at the moment, I mainly want to check the name strings between the NSMutableSets. @xlc

Comment: you can implement `isEqual:` and `hash` for your custom class. but Martin's answer should work if you only want to compare the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if the corresponding `name` attributes are identical, the following should work:

```
[[group valueForKeyPath:@"users.name"] isEqualToSet:[members valueForKey:@"name"]]
```

`[group valueForKeyPath:@"users.name"]` returns the set of the names of all users in the group, and `[members valueForKey:@"name"]` returns the set of the names of all users in the `members` set.

*Update:* As it became clear in the comments, `members` is a set of strings, and not a set of user objects. Therefore the code simplifies to:

```
[[group valueForKeyPath:@"users.name"] isEqualToSet:members]
```

Comment: Firstly, @martin you sir are a gem! Thanks for helping me out and thanks for helping the SO community out. I will give you the checkmark and upvote that you would deserve for typical code, but my noobish code unfortunately is a little weird. I get an error: `'[<__NSCFString 0xa268260> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'` It looks like I will have to implement isEqual: and hash as suggested above.

Comment: @GangstaGraham: That sounds as if `members` is a set of strings, and not a set of user objects. Try `[[group valueForKeyPath:@"users.name"] isEqualToSet:members]`.

Comment: Woohoo!!!!! @martin That worked. Yes, I just remembered members is in fact a set of strings, after looking back at my code, that is correct! Good job. I would double upvote this answer if I could. Thanks once again. :)