# Filter core data array field by array of values

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have core data model:

```
class Person: NSObject {
   var personName: String?
   var fruits: [String]?
}
```

There are two records sample in JSON format:

Person 1:

```
{
  "name" : "John",
  "fruits" : ["banana", "apple", "peach", "orange"]
}
```

Person 2:

```
{
  "name" : "Alice",
  "fruits" : ["cherry", "mango", "pear", "strawberry"]
}
```

I want to filter result to receive only person who like `cherry` and `mango`. 
I have

```
var fruitFilter: [String] = ["cherry", "mango"]
```

How I can use NSPredicate to fetch filtered entity?

```
var persons: [Person] = []

func fetchPersonWhoLike() {
  let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Person")
  request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "?????????", fruitFilter)
  ...
}
```

As result I should receive `persons` equals `["Alice"]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the "ALL" aggregate operation in a NSPredicate to filter a CoreData-based collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302611/how-to-use-the-all-aggregate-operation-in-a-nspredicate-to-filter-a-coredata-b)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a proper to-many relationship with a `Fruit` entity with, say, a `String` property `name`.

Then you can write a predicate like this:

```
let soughtFruits = ["cherry", "mango"]
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: 
    "SUBQUERY(fruits, $f, $f.name IN $@).@count = %d", soughtFruits, soughtFruits.count)
```

This will only work if there are no duplicates.