# Filter Core Data results by property IN array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I currently have Core Data successfully returning all of the results for a specific entity titled `Event`:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" 
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

One property of the Event entity is a string titled `tid`. I also have an array `filterArray` that contains all allowed tid values.

How can I get my Core Data request to only return events that have a tid property that matches one of the values in `filterArray`? I believe the answer relates to NSPredicate but I am not familiar enough with it yet to get it to bend to my will.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tid IN %@", filterArray];

[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Have a look at the [Aggregate Operations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891) in the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1).

**EDIT**

Have a look at [NSPredicate iPhone 3.2 SDK Core Data “IN clause” NSInvalidArgumentException exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062881/nspredicate-iphone-3-2-sdk-core-data-in-clause-nsinvalidargumentexception-excep). It's same error you have. The problem was a typo in the column/attribute name. The syntax should be alright, it can't just find `tid`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I attempted your suggestion but I am getting an 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (tid IN {1, 2})'. Any idea on this one?

Comment: Can I use NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tid IN[c] %@", filterArray]; for case insensitive?

Comment: @GuyKahlon have you figured out how to make an IN query case insensitive?

Comment: I guess doing a map on the array and lowercase every entry might be a solution.