# Subquery Predicate Core Data

Tags: ios, entity-framework, core-data

I have two Entity models "Content" and "LessonsContent" with no relationship between them. Both entities have common attribute "contentID" of NSNumber type. I am fetching all contents objects from "Content" entity for given predicate and storing these objects in contents array. I was successful in doing so.
Now, I want to fetch all lessonsContent objects from "LessonsContent" entity whose contentIds are present in contents array.

I am using following code:

```
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(contentType == %@)", @"Games"];


    NSError * error;
    NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Content class])];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSArray *contents = [[DELEGATE managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if(error){ NSLog(@"Error in fatching data");}


    //predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Content.contentID IN %@", contents];

    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(contents, $x, $x.Content.contentID IN %@).@count != 0)",contents];

    request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([LessonsContent class])];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray * mappingArray = [[DELEGATE managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"mappingArray %@", mappingArray);
```

But app is crashing. Please suggest appropriate solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the IN clause with your second predicate. 

[stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130900/filter-core-data-results-by-property-in-array

Comment: contentID attribute is NSNumber type. I already tried this but its not working.

Comment: I'd consider using `NSCompoundPredicate` and the convenience method `andPredicateUsingSubpredicates:` see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get an array of contentID's first. Then use IN.

```
NSArray *contents = [[DELEGATE managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSArray * allContentIDs = [contents valueForKey:@"contentID"];
```

then use the second predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contentID IN %@", allContentIDs];

[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Hope this helps.